# Did Steamboat Willie use this black and white poster for its theatrical release in 1928?

Tags: united-states, art

This [black and white theatrical poster of Steamboat Willie](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Steamboat_Willie#/media/File:Steamboat_Willie_1928_Poster.png) is available on wikipedia, which claims it was used in the 1928 release.

[image: Steamboat Willie]

But I can't find a reliable source that it's real. The source is just listed as `https://kith.com/blogs/kith/kith-x-disney-journal`, which seems a bit sketchy. Is there any picture of this theatrical poster or advertisement for Steamboat Willie taken from its feature debut (or any other posters). Is there anything that authenticates black and white poster?

Comment: There is a second link mentioned on the Wikimedia page: https://www.animationscoop.com/first-and-foremost-the-significance-of-steamboat-willie/, which looks a bit more reputable, although it also mentions no further sources.